# Firefox: Firefox prevented this page from automatically reloading

Tags: firefox, reload

Many websites are displayed in Firefox with this message which I cannot prevent in the Settings of Firefox.

Is there a setting in Firefox which disables this message ?

I use Firefox 84 on macOS 10.16.

Answer (score 1):

Finbally found.
It is a hidden setting, cannot be found in Preferences.

Looking for 'refresh' in about:config revealed
accessibility.blockautorefresh = true.

I set this to false and it is fixed !